# Obtener archivo enviado por POST

Tags: c#, post, http-post, multipart

Como obtengo el archivo que se recibe aca:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

estoy adjuntando el archivo asi, pero se envia sin extension y con un nombre que no quiero

```html
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
              
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.LocalFileName));
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era mas facil de lo que pense.

Quedo resuelto de la siguiente manera.

```html
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "Nombre del Documento";                  
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(file.LocalFileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf); //Attachment tiene varias sobrecargas
                    data.Name = subject;
                    mail.Attachments.Add(data);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigue este ejemplo, te ayudará, mira en el foreach fileHeaders

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType); 

    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
    {
        var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.
    }

    return Ok();
}
```